# "Hello world" android project, straight from book, yielding ActivityNotFoundException sometimes

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm just learning to work with Android through a textbook (Learn Android App Development by Jackson). At the moment, I have a MainActivity class. I'm adding Intents to the menu of this activity to launch one of four other activities depending on which option. All activities are in the same package, and all have been declared in the AndroidManifest.XML file.

I am determining which activity to run using a Switch case as follows:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_add:
        System.out.println("Add");
        Intent intent_add = new Intent(this, NewPlanet.class);
        this.startActivity(intent_add);
        break;
    case R.id.menu_attack:
        System.out.println("Attack");
        Intent intent_attack = new Intent(this, AttackActivity.class);
        this.startActivity(intent_attack);
        break;
    case R.id.menu_config:
        System.out.println("Config");
        Intent intent_config = new Intent(this, ConfigActivity.class);
        this.startActivity(intent_config);
        break;  
    case R.id.menu_travel:
        System.out.println("Travel");
        Intent intent_travel = new Intent(this, TravelActivity.class);
        this.startActivity(intent_travel);
        break;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    System.out.println("Outside switch.");
    return true;
}
```

The problem, however, is that this only works when pressing the "Add" menu button, which successfully launches the NewPlanet activity and displays it.

All of the others, however, produce an ActivityNotFoundException and force the program to crash (same result on various combinations of virtual devices, as well as on my physical Galaxy Note II device).

I've done everything I can think of to try to fix this to no avail. As far as I know, the code is identical to that presented in the book, but the book has begun to move onto the next sections while my project is not yet working yet.

I have LogCat output if anybody wants to see that, but any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. I've Googled the issue which did not help much.

EDIT: As requested, here is my Manifest: (I attached it as a high-res images since I'm having trouble with the editor right now)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDDUG.png

And here is the relevant LogCat output:

```
07-03 10:42:53.954: E/AndroidRuntime(29754): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-03 10:42:53.954: E/AndroidRuntime(29754): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {chapter.two.hello_world/chapter.two.hello_world.ConfigActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

FINAL EDIT:

I've solved this problem thanks to user E. Odebugg: I was referring to my activities in the manifest by incorrect names (ConfigPlanet instead of ConfigActivity). I simply did not notice the difference. A silly mistake, but it has been fixed now. Thank you everybody for your help!

Comment: Can you include your xml file too please.

Comment: Can you post your manifest file?

Comment: I have editted the main post to contain the LogCat output, as well as a screenshot of my AndroidManifest.xml. Is this the XML file you were interested in, btse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be something wrong with your manifest. Maybe you copied and pasted the same attributes for all Activities and hence have multiple Launcher IntentFilter Categories. Can you post both, the stack trace and the Manifest?

Comment: Have you tried adding <intent-filter >
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   </intent-filter> to each Activity besides the Main one?

Comment: I have not tried that as the book has not mentioned <intent-filter> tags in any way yet. I'll try that now and report back. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: I'm getting a flagged error by the IDE: "Element type "activity" must be followed by either attribute specfications ">" or "/>". I know my formatting is sound because I compared it directly to your suggestion, as well as to the formatting of the other intent-filter tag in the MainActivity class.

Comment: I see what your problem is. In the manifest you are declaring the name of your Activity as ConfigPlanet. But when you are calling the intent you say its name is ConfigActivity, just use one name

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much E. Odebugg, I really appreciate it. What a silly mistake by my part, but thank you sincerely for taking the time to find and point that out to me.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, the screen-shot you have shared shows that you have declared some **ConfigPlanet** activity, while in your switch-case u are calling **ConfigActivity**.

Replace .ConfigPlanet from your AndroidManifest.xml with .ConfigActivity, making sure that you do have a ConfigActivity.java file in your proper package.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have the `ConfigActivity` declared in your manifest.
Somehow you have an entry there for `ConfigPlanet` which is not the same. So that's the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all your activities are declared in your AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<manifest ... >
  <application ... >
      <activity android:name="your.packagename.AttackActivity" />
      <activity android:name="your.packagename.ConfigActivity" />
      <activity android:name="your.packagename.TravelActivity" />
      ...
  </application ... >
  ...
</manifest >
```

For details, see http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html

Comment: They are each defined exactly as shown by you here. All activities are declared the same (Except MainActivity, which was created by the IDE by default and declared in the manifest by default). The others are identical in their declaration, yet only one is functional (without crashing).